# R cannot allocate vector when merging data frames

Tags: r, memory, merge

I'm trying to merge two data frames A and B. A has about 45,000 rows and 25 columns and is of size 7.39 MB, according to `object_size()`. B has about 122,000 rows and 36 columns, although only 2 columns are involved in the merge. B is of size 32.6 MB. Here is my merge code:

```
A <- merge(x=A, y=B[,c("col1","col2")], by="col1", all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

When I try to run the merge: I get these error messages:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.6 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In merge.data.frame(x = bat.2007.2014, y = mlb.ebis.keys[, c("player_id",  :
  Reached total allocation of 12186Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In merge.data.frame(x = bat.2007.2014, y = mlb.ebis.keys[, c("player_id",  :
  Reached total allocation of 12186Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In merge.data.frame(x = bat.2007.2014, y = mlb.ebis.keys[, c("player_id",  :
  Reached total allocation of 12186Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In merge.data.frame(x = bat.2007.2014, y = mlb.ebis.keys[, c("player_id",  :
  Reached total allocation of 12186Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

I'm running Windows 10 and R version 3.3.1 (64-bit). My machine has 12 GB of RAM.

Both of these data frames seem to be of moderate size. Why am I running out of memory?

Comment: 6.6GB is pretty huge. You've already used RAM within your R session, R itself uses RAM, Windows uses RAM, other programs use RAM, etc. So with only 12 GB total RAM it's unsurprising a 6.6 GB vector is too big. Most likely the problem is with the join. Perhaps you're creating many copies of rows. For instance is `col1` is not a unique key that identifies each record once and only once in each dataset, but rather describes multiple rows, then you'll be create an exponentially bigger dataset with `merge`.

Comment: What are `length(unique(A$col1))` and `length(unique(B$col1))`? The joins done by `merge` are "Cartesian".

Comment: @42- The unique lengths by `col1` are 2024 and 73,216 respectively. A has 36,425 rows where `col1` is NA.

Comment: If you have a lot of replicated values of keys on both sides of the join, the number of matches explodes multiplicatively. (The meaning of a "Cartesian product".)

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I'm working on removing the duplicated keys and the merges are proceeding smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

check if your colnames to be merged by, match exactly. I had a similar problem, most likely reason for this abnormal allocation of memory. and yes, the primary is should always be unique.